# Emacs for better SVN workflow

Tags: svn

Because Xcode 10 no longer supports SVN I am looking for something to replace it. It seems as a good time to learn to use Emacs for SVN management.

The answer could be a single tool or easy Emacs flows (transition between Emacs tools that don't take much time and cognition). You could also give example of what are your SVN/Emacs most used work flows.

FYI I am Emacs noob.

**Minimal functionality that I would like:**

1. List all modified files. Select a file from the list and see a diff
   for working and base. Be able to modify working right inside the
   diff.

**Extra/Optional functionality:**

1. Be able to select which files to commit. Be able to select which lines to commit and which to skip. This point implies having point 1 from *minimal functionality*.
2. Have tortoisesvn-like ease of use for when using commits log. Be able to log commits. Have a way to filter them(including using the name of the file or part of its path as a viable way to filter). Select a commit from the list and see all the files it has changed. Choose a file from that list and see a diff of the changes that it has made.
3. Creating/applying patch for one or multiple files. (This is not that
   hard to do trough svn command so it is not that important)

**Emacs integration into SVN(Optional / Nice to have)**:

How can I setup Emacs as external help application for everything in ~/.subversion/config

These are the ones that I know what they do and use:

- *# editor-cmd*. This should do here `editor-cmd = emacs`
- *# diff-cmd* - I should be able to save diff as patch when using this. By default I can do `svn diff >> myFix.patch`.
- *# diff3-cmd*
- *# merge-tool-cmd*

My thoughts on the matter in this [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/44865/20374)

Comment: What have you looked for already?  Searching for "Emacs SVN mode" gives several relevant links.

Comment: You can see my answer for what I have looked for. Didn't want to make the question too long for including it in there.

Comment: Emacs comes with a lot of support for SVN built-in. You can find the documentation from Emacs by opening the manual (`C-h r`), then going to the version control chapter (`m version control <return>`). I think it would be worthwhile to read through that to learn the usual Emacs SVN workflow, before spending too much time recreating your own.

Comment: Thanks I will try to find some time to read trough the whole Version Control Emacs manual. Have just read partially from it when googling for stuff.

Answer (score 3):

These are from my limited knowledge and research.

**Options for minimal functionality**

1. inside the svn project directory `emacs -nw -f vc-root-diff`  ->
   `C-c C-e` for opening multiple diff in ediff. I actualy think this is not bad. Can't I skip the `vc-root-diff` step in any way? `ediff-directory-revisions` doesn't quite do the trick. An alternative way is using `emacs -nw -f vc-dir` which will give you something close to svn status and you can select a file and use `M-x vc-ediff` on it.

**Options for extra functionality:**

1. For selecting files you could do `C-x-v-d` in an open emacs inside the `svn` project directory. Then `m` to mark the files you want and then `v` for next action which should be *commit*. Write your message and `C-c C-c` to commit. You could reload the buffer with `g` in order to "not see" the files you just committed. **warning** the status buffer that you are working with will not show files that are with svn status `!` (aka files you have deleted using the OS file explorer). Dunno about selecting individual lines.
2. Use `svn log -v | less` -> filter trough search :) or before piping to `less` pipe to some elaborate `sed` script that filters -> copy the name of the file that you want to see the diffs for -> use `ediff-revisions` on that file. (This flow user experience is not that good)
3. Here I could probably use `vc-root-diff` -> edit if needed -> save as patch. Dunno how to apply that patch trough Emacs. `svn patch` has no way to resolve conflicts other than by hand.

**Options for Emacs integration into SVN**

For using Emacs with `diff-cmd` and `diff3-cmd` I found [these scripts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html#svn.advanced.externaldifftools.diff.ex-1) and adjusted them for Emacs. **These are not tested** because I am not sure they are correctly written. Would love some one to correct me:

diffwrap.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
emacs --eval "(ediff-files $6 $7 ())"

# Do I need this or is that handled by ediff?
# Return an errorcode of 0 if no differences were detected, 1 if some were.
# Any other errorcode will be treated as fatal.
```

diff3wrap.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
emacs --eval "(ediff3 $10 $9 $11)"

# Do I need this or is it handled by ediff?
# After performing the merge, this script needs to print the contents
# of the merged file to stdout.  Do that in whatever way you see fit.
# Return an errorcode of 0 on successful merge, 1 if unresolved conflicts
# remain in the result.  Any other errorcode will be treated as fatal.
```

For `merge-tool-cmd` something like this maybe:

```
#!/bin/sh
emacs --eval "(ediff-merge-files-with-ancestor $2 $3 $1 () $4)"
```

Comment: I think you're approaching this from the wrong angle: you should use `vc-dir` from *inside* emacs to do add/commit/diff etc, rather than calling various emacs commands from your shell. This implies starting emacs only once.

Comment: What @rpluim said: people tend to live *in* emacs; they don't just start it up to do one thing and then shut it down again.

Comment: Ok sure I could possibly open one Emac to use as SVN client. I might try that approach and see what happens. I believe however that I would have to use `M-!` to execute some SVN commands like `svn status`. I don't see another way to check for missing SVN files from Emacs. `svn log`'s `-v` and `-g` flags is another such instance. Truth is I haven't read the whole versioning documentation in Emacs and google doesn't give me the answers :/

Answer (score 2):

I use `psvn.el`.

You will have to download and place this file into a folder which is in the search path of your Emacs:
`(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp")`
Further you will have to compile this file to an .elc file.

If you run `svn-status` and select the root of your SVN checked out folder, you will get a nice overview in a separate buffer (`*svn-status*`) about your SVN checkout: modified files, unknown files, ... From there you can commit files by selecting them or marking several of them and pressing `c`. Or you can add add unknown files using `a`.

For further options and commands have a look at the SVN section in your menu bar or see the 'svn-status-...' commands (when using 'helm M-x').

Also see this link: http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-vcs/EmacsPSVN.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you elaborate?